# Save rotated Bitmap

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, camera, orientation

itI take a picture from the camera and I simply want to save it with the correct orientation.

I know their is quite a few post about that subject but even after reading all the answers I got stuck to save my rotated Bitmap.

So here si my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile
            .getAbsolutePath());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(finalOrientation);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    findViewById(R.id.image_preview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_preview)).setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
    findViewById(R.id.surfaceView).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(outputStream != null)
    {
        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I show up my Bitmap image in an image view to be sure it's in the correct orientation and it is. But it's only when I save (compress) it that it returns to her original state.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I didn't get you well can you please elaborate more? I mean what's the problem with your code?

Comment: The problem is : I take a picture in portrait orientation and it save it into landscape orientation. And what I wanted to show is that when I display my bitmap in an imageView, she's in the right orientation (on the screen, but not in the file explorer). Hope I'm clear enough :/

Comment: Please use _it_ for things and software entities; _he_ and _she_ are for persons.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: AFAIK the GIF format has attributes that control rotation by N*90 degrees. The Camera app used to support it (at least on some devices), while the Java classes ignored it. Probably it is that N*90 feature.

Answer (score 0):

This ***is not an answer***, but I want to post some code that might shed light on what is going on, and it does not fit into a comment:

```
ExifInterface exif;
int rotate = 0;
try {
       exif = new ExifInterface (file.getAbsolutePath());
       int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
       switch (exifOrientation) {
       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: rotate = 1 /*90*/; break;
       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: rotate = 2 /*180*/; break;
       case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: rotate = 3 /*270*/; break;
       }
} catch (IOException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d(TAG,"~~~~~~ exifOrientation: rotate="+rotate);
```